# Configuring / Implementing Apache on cPanel

Tags: angularjs, apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I'll start by saying I am completely new to Apache.

I'm trying to make my way through this particular tutorial about enabling rich social sharing in an Angular.js app: http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app#_section-set-up-the-server-side-script

The author mentions three specific Apache modules that need to be enabled: mod_rewrite, mod_proxy and mod_proxy_

My question is - are these modules enabled by default on cPanel? Is there somewhere that I can see them in the user interface? How do I know they can be accessed for the particular domain I'm working on?